# how to deploy my flask application on google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have trained a deep learning model and for the Ui part i used flask module.

I have a trained model which is of size 900MB.

I am not able to **deploy this flask application on google app engine** because of the **memory issue** of the trained model.

can anyone help me with how to **deploy** my flask application on google App engine?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if App Engine is the best place for something like deep learning, but anyhow: You have to change the [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) for your project.

Since you've mentioned 900 MB, your only options are B4_1G and B8 as classes. You can change this adding the option `instance_class: B8` to your [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#scaling_elements) file

Comment: can you suggest me any other source to deploy such applications?

Comment: I'm not a Deep Learning expert (I just know that it may be too much for App Engine). If you want to keep everything in GCP, I know from some [other technologies](https://cloud.google.com/products/ai/) for deep learning, and some [community ideas](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-using-flask-docker-and-google-cloud-platform-gcp-6e7bf1b339d5)